# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.' is inaccessible to class 'com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd'

Tags: java, android

Tratando de agregar **firebase analytics** me encuentro con este problema: (ya lei y probe esta solucion de [stackoverflow en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41955051/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-method-void-android-support-v4-content-contextcom) y no me soluciona)

> Error log:
>
> Task exception on worker thread: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.()' is inaccessible to class 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' appears

```
dependencias in app

> dependencies {
>     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
>     androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',
> {
>         exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
>     })
>     //compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
>     compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'
> 
>     //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
>     //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
> 
>     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
> 
>     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
>     compile files('libs/Android-SimpleLocation.jar')
>     compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar') //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
>     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'
>     compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
>     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.0'
>     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
> 
> }
```

Comment: Pero cual de todas las soluciones

Comment: ya probe todo lo que dicen ahi ...

Comment: Me parece que es un conflicto con la librería de Facebook usando las versiones 25.1.0 de android SDK, cambia a versión :   compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.29.0' y me comentas resultados!

Comment: Mira fue mas complicado que eso, pero gracias a tu ayuda empeze borrando el sdk de facebook y luego resolvi los errores que fueron surgiendo con stackoverflow y ya puedo ver en firebase analyitics muchisimas gracias !